# Serialization and Deserialization

Tags: java, serialization

I have several objects that I serialized and now need to edit, is there an approach to this without losing all the data I had stored in the files using the serialization.

**EDIT** [from comment] I dont need to edit the objects themselves I need to edit the Objects code, such as adding methods to it.

Comment: You'll have a hard time editing serialized streams, if that's what you're talking about. If it isn't, your question remains unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I dont need to edit the objects themselves I need to edit the Objects code, such as adding methods to it

Aha. An actual problem. OK.

1. Run the `serialver` utility on the .class files as they are now.
2. Add the declarations output by `serialver` to the source code of each class respectively.
3. Have a really good look at the [Versioning chapter of the Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html) to see what you can and cannot do while retaining compatibility with the existing stream.

Comment: @peter.petrov Well it took half a dozen questions to elicit it. It's like pulling teeth.

Comment: Sorry I should have made it more clear thanks for sticking with me. The link you sent me in Number 3, doesn't say anything about adding or removing methods or I missed it. So can I add methods to the class that is serialized?

Answer (score 1):

Load the objects in memory, edit the objects themselves, then save them back.
This is the safest way of doing it (if not the only way).

Comment: Okay so in the Compiler I should run it in debug mode then edit and resave the objects?

Comment: Doesn't need to be in debug mode. Just load your objects from disk, change them (with whatever values you want to set into them), save them back to disk.

Comment: @BrentColeman In the compiler? Do you mean the IDE? What does the IDE have to do with it? Where is it mentioned in your question? What *is* your question?

Comment: @EJP I assumed that's what OP meant.

Comment: I dont need to edit the objects themselves I need to edit the Objects code, such as adding methods to it.

Comment: @peter.petrov I don't have any problem with your answer, just with the question(s).

Comment: @EJP Yes, I know that, I just stated what I assumed.

Comment: @BrentColeman Maybe you should rephrase in details your question and explain exactly what situation you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @peter.petrov Then I dont' know why you're addressing me at all.